# Matlab integration

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I wrote a code in matlab to compute an integral using Gauss-Chebyshev quadrature , but it doesn't work:

```
function int = chebquad('-1i*exp(x+3)',1e-8,-1,1); 
f=inline('-1i*exp(x+3)','x')  
old_int = inf; 
for n=1:1000    
    x = cos(((2*(1:n) - 1)/(2*n))*pi);    
    w = pi/n;    
    fx = f(x);    
    int = sum(w.*fx);    
    if abs(int_old-int) < tol 
        break    
    end    
    old_int = int;   
end
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Are you asking it to return an "int" value?  Wouldn't a floating point number be a better idea?  Are you integrating the function with the exp or the cosine?  Please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am triying to calculate the definite integral -i times int e^(x+3) / \sqrt(1-x^2) from -1 to 1,  ie I am triying to integrate the exponential function , the cosine is the weight function,  it doesnt work because matlab gives  this error  Error: File: int.m Line: 1 Column: 27
Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Comment: Sorry, is that "i" equal to the square root of negative one or a loop counter?

Comment: indeed i is a complex number i= √-1

Comment: That's what I assumed - see some answers below.

Comment: @duffymo - just because the variable is named int, does NOT make it an integer. int will be a double here.

Comment: Do you see an issue with using a keyword like "int" as a variable name?  I do.  Even if it "works", it makes the code unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for future reference, it would help us out that you didn't display your function with the specified variable as constants:

so show:

```
function hv= someName(firstVar, secondVar)
```

and not:

```
function hv= someName(1, 'some string')
```

I don't know why you have both -1 and 1, but I'm assuming tol = 1e-8. That being said, you made a small mistake in your code by using `int_old` instead of `old_int.`

Edit: so at first I thought, you just displayed the function for "our benefit", now I think you didn't even define a Matlab function properly. Please [read this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function.html) and learn about basic Matlab coding. Chebyshev–Gauss quadrature is defined over `-1 to 1`, and thus doesn't need to be in a function code, below is the revised code:

```
function intV = chebquad(funC,tol)

f=inline(funC,'x');
old_int = inf; 
for n=1:1000    
    x = cos(((2*(1:n) - 1)/(2*n))*pi);    
    w = pi/n;    
    fx = f(x);    
    intV = sum(w.*fx);    
    if abs(old_int - intV) < tol 
        break    
    end    
    old_int = intV ;   
end
```

at the command prompt, you call this with:

```
intV = chebquad('-1i*exp(x+3)', 1e-8)
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know the answer and what the function looks like before you start.  Here's what Wolfram Alpha says about your function:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+-i+*exp%28x%2B3%29%2Fsqrt%281-x%5E2%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20-i%20%2aexp%28x%2b3%29/sqrt%281-x%5E2%29)

And here's what the answer should be:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int++-i+*exp%28x%2B3%29%2Fsqrt%281-x%5E2%29%2C+x%3D-1..1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%20-i%20%2aexp%28x%2b3%29/sqrt%281-x%5E2%29,%20x=-1..1)

See if that helps.

Comment: Of course, I knew the result, I know that wolpramalpha exits ;) , but Do you know what is  wrong in the first line of my code?, the 1e^-8 is the accuracy of the solution